# Quadratic Functions: Determine the value of b

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, quadratics

I'm having trouble with this question and I'm not sure what to do. Would appreciate any one who helps me out.

Question: The point $(-2,1)$ is on the graph of the quadratic function: $f(x) = -x^2 + bx + 11$. Determine the value of $b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $(p,q)$ is on the graph of $y = g(x)$, then we know that $q = g(p)$. So just replace $x$ with $-2$ and replace $f(x)$ with $1$, then solve for $b$.

Comment: I got an answer of 7, when the answer should be 3.

Comment: Remember that $-(-2)^2 = -4$, not $4$.

Comment: \begin{align*}
f(-2) &= -(-2)^2 + b(-2) + 11 \\
1 &= -4 - 2b + 11 \\
1 &= -2b + 7 \\
-6 &= -2b \\
b &= 3
\end{align*}